# ng-repeat on inner elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an application that has assets and each of these assets has a number of notes. Now in my application i am looping my assets and in there i am looping my notes. like so

```
<div class="asset-image-container" ng-repeat="asset in assets" data-asset-key="{{ asset.key }}">
                <img class="asset-page" src="{{asset.large_asset_path}}"/>
                <div ng-repeat="note in asset.notes" class="note-pin" data-note-index="{{ note.index }}" data-asset-key="{{ asset.key }}"  style="left: {{ note.x }}%; top: {{ note.y }}%;">
                    <span class="note-index">{{ note.index }}</span>
                    <img src="/img/note.png">
                </div>
```

On this same page i would also like to show all my notes in a list without the assets. so i need 2 ng-repeats but the first one should be without an html element. Any idea ho  i might manage this?

Update:

i have added my model to make it more clear:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":69,
      "upload_id":16,
      "name":"preview-1",
      "key":"l476IU94c9YhyvUByZnnr162bbO3uKs3bcWVXSpG",
      "created_at":"2014-11-25 20:41:30",
      "updated_at":"2014-11-25 20:41:30",
      "deleted_at":null,
      "large_asset_path":"\/uploads\/vtbwCn1ISkRYCewaYtQE9qwDdXmpWcUohlcQAnzc\/large\/preview-1.jpg",
      "small_asset_path":"\/uploads\/vtbwCn1ISkRYCewaYtQE9qwDdXmpWcUohlcQAnzc\/small\/preview-1.jpg",
      "notes":[  
         {  
            "id":13,
            "index":13,
            "key":"oidSFwkyYhPmA9TK0XCLU4Jg52nJHA2E9CIv59Lw",
            "upload_id":16,
            "asset_id":69,
            "from_id":1,
            "message":"\n            ",
            "created_at":"2014-12-07 08:46:58",
            "updated_at":"2014-12-07 08:47:52",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "x":"71.67796920821115",
            "y":"8.503401360544217",
            "parameters":[  
               {  
                  "id":25,
                  "note_id":13,
                  "name":"x",
                  "value":"71.67796920821115",
                  "created_at":"2014-12-07 08:46:58",
                  "updated_at":"2014-12-07 08:47:51",
                  "deleted_at":null
               },
               {  
                  "id":26,
                  "note_id":13,
                  "name":"y",
                  "value":"8.503401360544217",
                  "created_at":"2014-12-07 08:46:58",
                  "updated_at":"2014-12-07 08:46:58",
                  "deleted_at":null
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "id":63,
            "index":50,
            "key":"CRZGM6XbRJzgWyq4Vmt1BUuRnOlBCnNQs4lHGRu8",
            "upload_id":16,
            "asset_id":69,
            "from_id":1,
            "message":null,
            "created_at":"2014-12-07 08:49:21",
            "updated_at":"2014-12-07 08:49:21",
            "deleted_at":null,
            "x":"0",
            "y":"0",
            "parameters":[  
               {  
                  "id":125,
                  "note_id":63,
                  "name":"x",
                  "value":"0",
                  "created_at":"2014-12-07 08:49:21",
                  "updated_at":"2014-12-07 08:49:21",
                  "deleted_at":null
               },
               {  
                  "id":126,
                  "note_id":63,
                  "name":"y",
                  "value":"0",
                  "created_at":"2014-12-07 08:49:21",
                  "updated_at":"2014-12-07 08:49:21",
                  "deleted_at":null
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      "upload":{  
         "id":16,
         "key":"vtbwCn1ISkRYCewaYtQE9qwDdXmpWcUohlcQAnzc",
         "name":"annots.pdf",
         "type":"application\/pdf",
         "size":393314,
         "status_id":1,
         "created_at":"2014-11-25 20:41:29",
         "updated_at":"2014-11-25 20:41:29",
         "deleted_at":null
      }
   },
   ...
]
```

Comment: Why not just fix your data model to create a list of notes and iterate only over the notes and not both assets and notes?

Comment: Can you please post your model as it would make it a lot easier to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

As Phill stated, I suggest you to create a list of notes and then iterate  over them, something like the following:

```
for (var i = 0, asset; asset = $scope.assets[i]; i++) {
  $scope.notes = $scope.notes || [];
  $scope.notes.concat(asset.notes);
}
```

Then in the view:

```
<div ng-repeat="note in notes">
   {{note}}
</div>
```